# coloring specific data in an arrow plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

i do a plot of my data set in arrow, and i want to color just a specific data ( a specific arrow) how i can select it ? (i can filter on it and set him like a df) i don't kwow why he couldn't be implemented in my ggplot.

Here's an exemple of my dataset, and i know to color just one arrow(specific arrow) for exemple.

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(ID = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2,3)), year = rep(2018:2020, 2), x = c(1.2, 1.6, -1.1, 3.2, 3.8, 1.9), y = c(3, -2, 6, -1, 2, 3)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(label = ifelse(row_number() == 1, ID, "")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, label = label, group = ID)) + 
  geom_path(arrow = arrow()) + 
  geom_text(nudge_x = .2, nudge_y = 0)
```

Thanks you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `mapping = aes(color = as.factor(year))` in your `geom_path`,

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(ID = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2,3)), year = rep(2018:2020, 2), x = c(1.2, 1.6, -1.1, 3.2, 3.8, 1.9), y = c(3, -2, 6, -1, 2, 3)) %>% 
        group_by(ID) %>% 
        mutate(label = ifelse(row_number() == 1, ID, "")) %>% 
        ungroup() %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, label = label, group = ID)) + 
        geom_path(arrow = arrow(),mapping = aes(color = as.factor(year))) + 
        geom_text(nudge_x = .2, nudge_y = 0)
```

[image]

If you want to `color` one specific `arrow`, here I colored for 2020, you can add a new layer.

```
data <- tibble(ID = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2,3)), year = rep(2018:2020, 2), x = c(1.2, 1.6, -1.1, 3.2, 3.8, 1.9), y = c(3, -2, 6, -1, 2, 3)) %>% 
        group_by(ID) %>% 
        mutate(label = ifelse(row_number() == 1, ID, "")) %>% 
        ungroup()

data %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, label = label, group = ID)) + 
        geom_path(arrow = arrow()) + 
        geom_path(data = data %>% filter(year == 2020),arrow = arrow(),mapping = aes(color = as.factor(year), group = 1)) + 
        geom_text(nudge_x = .2, nudge_y = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: i want to color just one vector for exemple x = c(1.2, 1.6, -1.1) y = c(3, -2, 6), not all the dataset

Comment: Ive updated my answer, how does this work for you?

Comment: It's help me to find my solution, thanks you very much