# How to give arrows only to certain lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse, arrows

Say that I have lines as follows (with code taken directly from [coloring specific data in an arrow plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68497042/coloring-specific-data-in-an-arrow-plot-in-r)):

```
data <- tibble(ID = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2,3)), year = rep(2018:2020, 2), x = c(1.2, 1.6, -1.1, 3.2, 3.8, 1.9), y = c(3, -2, 6, -1, 2, 3)) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(label = ifelse(row_number() == 1, ID, "")) %>% 
    ungroup()

data %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, label = label, group = ID)) + 
    geom_path(arrow = arrow()) + 
    geom_path(data = data %>% filter(year == 2020),arrow = arrow(),mapping = aes(color = as.factor(year), group = 1)) + 
    geom_text(nudge_x = .2, nudge_y = 0)
```

If I wanted to only have line 1 have an error, how would I do this? Would I have to graph the lines separately from the arrows (and filter as is done in the code below)?

Comment: Since geom_path() only "understands the following aesthetics: x, y, alpha, colour, group, linetype, linewidth" (from `?geom_path`), I expect you can't map `arrow` to `aes()` and you would need to make a separate layer for the parts you want an arrow vs. the ones you don't.